# Can't log in the iOS app with my Google account

Tags: support, login, ios-app, google

I use my Google account to log in on the Stack Exchange website, but on the iOS app the login is not working.

1. Press *Log in* on the app
2. Select *Log in using Google*
3. Put the Google account and password on the popup

Then I can only see a blank Google page (`accounts.google.com`) with the Google logo on top left and my email on the top right, and the only option is to log out from Google. On the browser there is a <kbd>End</kbd> button that send me to the app login page again.

The same is using Safari in private mode, logging out from every Google account, and setting the app to use Chrome (it always uses Safari anyway).

If I open the browser on the google.com page, I'm logged in correctly, but I am still cannot use the same account on the app.

This was tested with iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 5, both with iOS 9.1.

Comment: What device? What OS? Can you login into your gmail account using other app?

Comment: If you go to http://google.com in Safari, are you signed in or able to sign in with the "Sign in" button in the top right corner of the page?

Comment: @shadow I use an iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 9, other apps with Google account are working

Comment: @brian I'm signed in on the Google page

Comment: OK, so please add those details to the question, and hopefully Brian (the iOS dev) will take a look soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was a content blocker, after disabling it the Google login in app worked. 
It seem that the Google login in app is treated as unwanted ad.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with blocked cookies.

Here is the solution which helped me.

1. Go to Settings -> Safari -> under "Privacy & Security -> Block Cookies -> set it to "Always allow"
2. Try to login again.