# Problem logging into SE app on IOS using Google

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, login

I've been using the IOS StackExchange app for a couple of years now, without a problem. Today I got a new iPhone Xs, downloaded the app, and tried to log in using Google, the way I always do. Each time I tried, I got the error message shown below, so I'm doing what it says. All of my other Google logins on the same phone have worked fine, and my StackExchange/Google login works fine on my desktop. Is there some strange interaction among StackExchange, IOS, and Google that I'm not understanding?

I looked at [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272402/415824), with an answer suggesting unblocking cookies in Safari. I checked, and they are not blocked. I'm at a loss.

[image]

Comment: The error message is misleading; There's no point to report here since the app development is frozen and there's nobody to fix such bugs. thanks for reporting anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Oh, I see. Thanks for letting me know.